# C++ Assigning to an object variable?

Tags: c++, object, syntax

I am learning c++ coming from a java background, I understand that in Java everything is implicitly a pointer (except primitive types) and so I've been using pointers when I want to use a variable that jumps between already allocated instances of classes. 
What I would like to know is what happens when you do something like this:

```
class Thing1{
public:
    Thing1() {n = 10;}
    int n;
}

Thing1 A; // Creates an instance of Thing1
Thing1 B = A; // What happens here???
B.n = 5;
A.n = 16;
```

So two Thing1 objects get created on the stack right? Im confused about the behavior of assigning a variable containing an instance of a class to another instance of the class (assuming we dont overload the = operator). Any help?

Comment: `// What happens here???` Copy elision most of the time :-P ...

Comment: The `=` makes a copy of the object `A` and assigns it to `B`.  No different than if you were assigning an `int` variable `int x; int y = 10; x = y;`.  This (to me) is much easier to comprehend than what Java does.  There are no hidden references here -- WYSIWYG, and that is a copy.

Comment: Objects in C++ primarily have value identity, and you can assign a value to an object. Basically, *all* objects in C++ are like the primitive types in Java. The reference semantics that you're familiar with from Java have to be implemented explicitly in C++ (or you can use native reference types for simple argument passing).

Comment: `Thing1() = {n = 10};` won't compile.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ why copy elision? There is no temporary involved, but just the default copy constructor.

Comment: @vsoftco Turned out being wrong syntax, anyway ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your code is very wrong in line:

```
 Thing1() = {n = 10};
```

It should be:

```
 Thing1() {n = 10;} // notice deleted = and semicolon position
```

And you need to end class definition with semicolon.

Now, to answer your question: If you use = operator between same class objects and without overloading, you just basically set all member variables of B to values from A and those two objeccts are still independent from each other.

---

It's like:

```
int a = 5, b = 10;
b = a; // b = 10 and a = 10
b = 3 // b = 3 and a = 10
```

---

Consider this working piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Thing1
{
    public:
        Thing1() {n = 10;}
        int n;
};


int main() 
{
    Thing1 A; // Creates an instance of Thing1
    Thing1 B = A; // What happens here???

    cout << B.n << endl << A.n << endl; // 10 10

    B.n = 5;
    A.n = 16;

    cout << B.n << endl << A.n; // 5 16

    return 0;
}
```

It prints out:

> 10
>   10
>   5
>   16

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of the line:
Thing1 B = A; // What happens here???

B is an object of type Thing1, the members of object B are initialized with the current value of members of object A. You are not assigning the pointer of object A to object B, but just making another copy of A. This is done using copy constructor in C++.

Changing any member of B does not reflect in the corresponding member of class A.